# Outlook 2007 - Right Click Email > Move To {Folder Name}

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I know it seems like an elementary question. What's the simplest and fastest way to move a read/completed email to a different folder in Outlook 2007 (connected to Exchange 2007)?

I have a particular user that is challenged by technology. Using keyboard shortcuts is not an option. Dragging and dropping things - forget it. And too many clicks is frustrating to him.

He keeps his email inbox completely clean (OCD=True) but he does that by deleting every single email as quickly as he's done with it. If an email can't be resolved in a day or two it almost drives him to insanity. As far as he's concerned, there's only one right thing to do with an email - reply to it and then delete it.

He's being asked to save emails unless they are clearly trash. I'm trying to figure out what the simplest method is to move an email to a "Saved Emails" or "Archived" folder (don't confuse "folder" with .PST file, that's irrelevant for this discussion).

I envisioned that I could possibly hi-jack every delete and put the email in his Saved folder. But I don't like this option because some emails are truly trash and I don't want him saving those.

What I'd really like to do is something like this:

```
Right Click Email in List > Move To {Folder Name}
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Maybe someone has another suggestion on how to handle this situation.

Comment: And what's wrong with Outlook 2007's *Move to Folder...* context menu option?

Comment: I'm already aware of that feature and it works, but it's at least one extra click, and possibly more if you have two or three folders.

Comment: Also, I think Outlook 2010 has a feature to facilitate this already called something like "Quick Steps". So I think it's a valid request/complaint.

Comment: In Outlook 2010 there is no even need to use Quick Steps for that. It provides *Move To...* submenu containing recently used folders.